# Probability of drawing letters from a word

Tags: probability, self-study

Two letters are drawn randomly from the word SENSATION with replacement.

What is the probability that the letters will be identical?

Answer attempt:

there are 9 possible letters to be drawn

the letter S and N occur twice, making the probability of each S: 2/9, N:2/9

Now I'm guessing that the probability that the letters drawn will be identical is 2/9*2/9 = 4/81 is that correct?

Comment: Here's a hint. There's 81 possible two letter pairs since there's 9 ways to pick the first and 9 to pick the second. That's your denominator. Can you figure the numerator out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have nine possible letters to draw: **S**,E,**N**,*S*,A,T,I,O, and *N*.
Because the draws are made with replacement (that is, you don't remove something from the sample set after you draw it), it is possible to draw each letter twice.
As such, the following pairs are all valid: (**S** , **S**), (E , E), (**N** , **N**), (*S* , *S*), (A , A), (T , T), (I , I), (O , O), and (*N* , *N*).
But, because both S and N appear twice, it is also possible to draw the other pairs (**S** , *S*), (*S* , **S**), (**N** , *N*), (*N* , **N**). This makes thirteen pairs where you have the same letter.
It should be fairly clear how many possible pairs there are in general, but I hope this clears up the confusion as to why all letters have to be considered.

Answer (score 3):

Each letter provides disjoint events.  So you can sum the probabilities both letters are the same for each letter.
So S an N give (2/9) (2/9) =4/81
and E, A, I, T and O each give (1/9) (1/9)=1/81
So 5 terms contribute 1/81 and 2 contribute 4/81.  Sum them to get the answer.

Comment: you mean sum 1/81 + 4/81? or sums 5*1/81 + 2*4/81 ?

Comment: It is 5/81+ 2*4/81.

Comment: can you please explain in more detail? I don't get it why the other letters count.

Comment: Sure.  You can pick E on the first draw with probability 1/9.  The E is returned and can be drawn again on the second draw also with probaility 1/9.  If the letters were not replaced then only the letters that appear twice in the original 9 could be picked twice.  But then the probability of S appearing twice would be (2/9) (1/8) =1/36 instead of 4/81.

Comment: yes, but first I look at S and N, both have probability 2/9 of being selected on the first and 2/9 on the second making the probability of two S or two Ns 4/81. Now what I don't understand is why this answer isn't sufficient and why we need to consider the remaining letters. Maybe if you explained to me in words what the 4/81 represents than I might get it. (thank you for your help)